# Finding all directories in a repository with svn property: svn-ignore

Tags: svn

How can I find all the directories in my svn repository with the property of svn:ignore?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
svn propget -R svn:ignore
```

Answer (score -1):

find . -type d > folders.txt
then copy the content of folders.txt (without the first line) to the svn:ingore file

You can also send the output of find directly into the svn:ingore file

Comment: Seems to be a misunderstanding: The question is about *finding* dirs with "svn:ignore", not setting it.